# ReferenceError: Can't find variable goto_detail_page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using Laravel 5.4.

I have this code in index.php:

```
<span class="input-group-btn">
     <button class="btn btn-default ripple" type="button" data-color="#39F2F9" onclick="goto_detail_page();">
        <img src="assets/images/search-icon.png" />

                        </button>
                    </span>
```

The script is added at the bottom of the page after footer callout. 
The script includes other modules that are also not working, i.e.. login module:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
        var msg = $('#msg').val();
        if (msg == "success") {
            $('#res-title').css('color','green');
            $('#res-title').html('Success');
            $('#res-content').html('Your account is activated successfully. You can login now.');
            $('#resultModal').modal({
            });
        }else if(msg == "failed"){
            $('#res-title').css('color','red');
            $('#res-title').html('Failed');
            $('#res-content').html('Something went wroing. Please try again later.');
            $('#resultModal').modal({
            });
        }
    });

var current_item_code="";

$(".search_medicine").autocomplete({
    search: function(event, ui) {
        $('.med_search_loader').css('display','block' );
    },
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $('.med_search_loader').css('display','none' );
    },
    source: '{{ URL::to('medicine/load-medicine-web/1' )}}',
    minLength: 0,
    delay: 0 ,
    select: function (event, ui) {
            item_code = ui.item.item_code;
            current_item_code=item_code;
     },
        response: function( event, ui ) {
         $('.med_search_loader').css('display','none' );
        }
})

function goto_detail_page()
     {
     var name=$(".search_medicine").val();
     if(current_item_code=="")
     {
        $.ajax({
        url: 'medicine/add-new-medicine',
        data: 'name='+name,
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) {
                if(data.status)
                {
                    $('#new_med_status').show();
                    $('#new_med_status').addClass('alert-success');
                    $('#new_med_status').html('This medicine is not available for now. Please check availability later.');
                    $("#new_med_status").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow");
                }else
                {
                    $('#new_med_status').show();
                    $('#new_med_status').addClass('alert-danger');
                    $('#new_med_status').html('Something went wrong. Please try again later.');
                    $("#new_med_status").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow");
                }
            }
        });
     }
     else{
        window.location="medicine-detail/"+current_item_code;
     }
     }

     $("#input-20").change(function() {
        if($('#input-20').val().length!=0)
        {
        $.ajax({
                url: 'user/check-session',
                type: 'GET',
                datatype: 'JSON',
                success: function (data) {
                        if(data==1)
                        {
                            $('#upload').click();
                        }else{
                            $('#loginModal').click();
                        }
                    }
                });

        }
     });

</script>
```

I have run that code above on the stack overflow simulator and it comes out with an error. I do not know what I am doing wrong with the code.

In my site, the jquery.min.js file is being loaded before this code.

Please help with the javascript code. It is an older code that I am working to adapt to the newer version of Laravel 5.4. The code works perfectly well with laravel 4.2.

Comment: Have you check your js code, there are syntex error with your js code. Remove the error first.

Comment: If I knew how, I wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: If you were a web developer, you'd knew how to check the javascript console within your browser?  It is not so [Farfetch'd](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Farfetch'd_(Pokémon)) as that link. And if you really, really are clueless and you agree with the last statement than it would be F12 in any browser, in any OS, the few exceptions are terminal based such as lynx.